# Pattern matching..error says Error:(11, 11) type mismatch; found : Unit

Tags: scala

Using `IntelliJ`. I have a `scala` worksheet file with this code. I am using patten matching. But I get this error:

```
Error:(11, 11) type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: String
  println(s"The donut $donutType taste level is $tastelevel")
         ^
      val donutType:String = "Glazed"
      val tastelevel: String  = donutType match{

      case "Glazed" => "Very1 tasty"

      case "Plain"  => "so so"

       println(s"The donut $donutType taste level is $tastelevel")

       }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Swap the `println` and the closing brace, because `println` returns `Unit` and this is what your `match` will return.
You code (as written) has two branches in the `match`. One returns `String`, which is what you want. The second branch ("so so") executes the following block of code: "Execute the constant `so so`, which returns a `String`. Discard the value. Execute the `println` statement, which returns `Unit`. End of the block, so return `Unit`". So the second block returns `Unit`. If the first block returns `String`  and the second one returns `Unit`, the compiler determines that the `match` statement returns `Unit`. But you want to assign the `match` to a `String` value, so there is a compilation error.

To fix this, execute the `println` outside of the closing brace of the `match` (i.e. after the `match`)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't understand.

Comment: Added explanation. Hope this helps